# Adjectif plus "à" plus infinitif

Tags: adjectifs, infinitif, constructions, à

> Une chose facile à dire.
>
> Villa prête à habiter.

Quels types d'adjectifs peuvent entrer dans des structures comme ci-dessus ?

Comment: *A priori* je ne vois pas d'adjectifs qui ne conviendraient pas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La condition ne repose pas en premier lieu sur l'adjectif mais sur le verbe.
Pour qu'une telle formule soit possible, il faut impérativement que le verbe soit **transitif**
(Qu'il puisse admettre un COD ou COI puisque c'est sur ce COD ou COI que va porter l'adjectif)

Formellement c'est tout.

Après, évidemment, il est tout de même préférable que la formule ait un sens.
Cette condition (non impérative puisque les poètes peuvent s'en dispenser) imposerait alors un adjectif compatible avec le champ sémantique.

On mange des pommes, des pommes sont bonnes => pommes bonnes à manger
On cuit des tartes, les tartes sont prêtes => tartes prêtes à cuire
Sur un navire, l'équipage est prêt pour une manœuvre => équipage paré à virer
... 
Tout donc...

Answer (score 1):

Complément à l'excellente réponse :

http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/037.html

> L’adjectif peut aussi être complété par un verbe dans la construction du type adjectif à infinitif (facile à lire, impossible à accepter). Cette construction est très fréquente en français.

http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/040.html

> La construction adjectif à infinitif est assez particulière, car l’adjectif forme un groupe sémantique avec l’in­fi­ni­tif. Dans une phrase comme la suivante :

> Ce film est trop long à expliquer.
> ce n’est pas le film qui est long (ce film est trop long), mais l’explication. Autrement dit, le nom (n) qui est le sujet du verbe est aussi sémantiquement l’objet direct de l’infinitif (lequel est formellement le complément de l’adjectif attribut du sujet). Cette structure cache ainsi une construction infinitive, qui contient un verbe transitif direct :

> Ce livre est facile à lire = Lire ce livre est facile. / Il est facile de lire ce livre.

Le sujet est difficile à aborder en quelques lignes : https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00208086/document